# get approved users only ( ultimate member plugin )

Tags: user-roles, users

I am using [UltimateMember](http://ultimate%20member%20plugin) and I have the settings configured that admin must approve registered users first. I now want to display the approved users meta information like faculty, email, etc. in the theme. So in this page template I've the following block of code to get all registered users information :

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'role' => 'contributor',
);

$users = get_users( $args );

foreach ( $users as $user ) {
    echo '<span>' . esc_html( $user->user_email ) . '</span>';
    echo '<span>' . esc_html( $user->faculty ) . '</span>';
    echo '<span>' . esc_html( $user->graduation_year ) . '</span>';
}
```

The problem is, that my code block is displaying all registered users information weather it is approved by admin or not.

Comment: Try `who` parameter instead of role. 

**who** - If set to 'authors', only authors (user level greater than 0) will be returned.

Comment: this even displayed admin information , i want to get users labeled 'approved' in the plugin and exclude users with status 'pending review'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your WP settings is

1. New User Default Role    = contributor

If yes, so this block of code shows all the contributor's with account_status = approved;

```
$args = array(
    'role'          =>  'contributor',
    'meta_key'      =>  'account_status',
    'meta_value'    =>  'approved'
);

$users = get_users($args);

foreach ($users as $user) {
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r( $user );
   echo '</pre>';
}
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users

Comment: great worked , i appreciate your help but can you explain to me how did you know there is a meta key with the name 'account_status' ?

Comment: Through guess first then checked into database. ;)

Comment: Yeah i wanted to to check in database but did not know where to dig exactly

Answer (score 0):

The plugin called Ultimate Member has this capability via the Ultimate Member settings > User roll.

Plugin URL: https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-member/